# Getting Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I am getting Error:UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL. The log shows to increase the heap size. I have added android:largeHeap = true in an application. Then also I am getting this error.

Manifest:

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon1"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Log:

```
To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has approximately 910 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 2048 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
Error:UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:  at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
Error:  at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:191)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:279)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:569)
Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:366)
Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)
Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
Error:  at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 7 mins 31.106 secs
Information:14 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

What to do?

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: *added android:largeHeap = true in an application*  ... for resolving compile/build time OOME ... brilliant idea ...

Comment: Avoid using largeHeap option as much as possible. It may cost you hard-to-notice performance drop and bad user experience.

Comment: dint get you @Selvin

Comment: How can I get rid of this error? @BOUTERBIATOualid

Comment: I am just trying to use geo coder and run the app and stuck on this error. @A.Omar

Comment: Sometimes restarting the developer environment solves the problem

Comment: I tried clean build as well as invalid caches restart. Not at all solving my problem. @CoolGuyCG

Comment: The log says "To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project gradle.properties." Have you tried this?

Comment: I dint get this. How and where to set? @asiew

Comment: Open your gradle.properties file in your project, and add the line "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M"

Comment: To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project gradle.properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The log says

> "To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project
>   gradle.properties."

So open your gradle.properties file and add the line "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M"

Answer (score 3):

In your `build.gradle` Try to add this :

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

- `incremental true` is using to speed up your builds.
- `javaMaxHeapSize "4g"` to specify the heap size for the dex process.

Comment: This option is deprecated. As of now on Android Studio 3.0.1 shows warning but prepares your build.

Answer (score 0):

Your log:

> To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project
>   gradle.properties